# Shared "Char * " in a C project

Tags: c, global-variables, shared-memory

i want to use a Char * across the project, the problem i am facing is below.

I created a header file as following:

File.h

```
extern char *a;
```

File1.c

```
#include "File.h"
char *a;
void foo()
{
    //some manipulation on a
}
```

File2.c

```
#include"File.h"
void foo1()
{
 //using "a" here gives a garbage value
}
```

I am sure that foo() is executed much before foo1().

Comment: Can you post the complete code for a small program that demonstrates the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check you have allocated bytes for the char *a using malloc()? If not, it will surely print garbage value. Also memset() the pointer after allocating so that it is initialized without any garbage

Answer (score 0):

Check are you initializing it correctly. Note that it is a pointer to char.